# XML parsing to get a particular tag value in a list of XElement

Tags: c#, xml, linq, xelement

I have below XML and c# code.
I want to get the list of values like `333,382` in a list present in `<Event >`tag.

However with below code i am getting the list of whole Event tag like`{ Event = "333" },{ Event = "382" }`

[image]

I can code few more logic to get only the numeric part out of it but for code efficiency its better to get the required value like `333,382` in eventList itself through LINQ.

Can somebody please help on it ? Thanks in advance.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;
using System.Xml.Linq;

namespace ConsoleApp1
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            string eventListXML= @"<XYZ>
                                    <Task>
                                        <ABC>
                                            <EvtLogResponse>
                                                <LogInfo>
                                                    <CommID>8</CommID>
                                                    <UserId>2</UserId>
                                                    <Date>10/09/2020</Date>
                                                    <Time>06:24:01 PM</Time>
                                                </LogInfo>
                                                <EventLogAllRes>
                                                    <EventOrRestore>E</EventOrRestore>
                                                    <Event>333</Event>
                                                </EventLogAllRes>
                                                <EventLogAllRes>
                                                    <EventOrRestore>E</EventOrRestore>
                                                    <Event>382</Event>
                                                </EventLogAllRes>
                                                <FilePath>C:\Windows\test.txt</FilePath>
                                            </EvtLogResponse>
                                            <UserID>1</UserID>
                                        </ABC>
                                    </Task>
                                </XYZ>";

            XDocument xDoc = XDocument.Parse(eventListXML);
            XElement Xele = xDoc.Element("XYZ").Element("Task").Element("ABC").Element("EvtLogResponse");
            List<XElement> Logs = Xele.Elements("EventLogAllRes").ToList<XElement>();


            var eventList = (from Event in Logs.Descendants("Event")
                             select new
                             {
                                 Event = Event.Value

                             }).ToList();
             
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: It looks like you just need to remove the `new { Event =` and corresponding `}`. Although the trailing `,` makes me wonder if there is more code there.

Comment: var values = XDocument.Parse(eventListXML)
        .Element("XYZ")
        .Element("Task")
        .Element("ABC")
        .Element("EvtLogResponse")
        .Elements("EventLogAllRes")
        .Select(x => x.Element("Event").Value);

Comment: Try following : Event.SetValue(string.Empty));

Comment: Thx but not very elegant answer. Prefer something lighter like @Price Khanna. You can also use XPath query like`XDocument.Parse(eventListXML).XPathSelectElements("//Event").Select(x => x.Value)`.

Answer (score 1):

You want it to be like list of integers right??

Just remove make a new Event and code like below

```
var eventList = (from Event in Logs.Descendants("Event")
                                 select 
                                     Regex.Replace(Event.Value.ToString(), "[^0-9]+", string.Empty)).ToList();
```

Further if you want to have comma separated values then add below code to the code above.

```
var result = String.Join(",", eventList);
```

Here result will have the comma separated string.

Let me know if more anything else is needed.